# Examine Request Headers with ServiceStack

Tags: asp.net, servicestack

What is the best way to inspect the Request Headers for a service endpoint?

```
ContactService : Service
```

Having read this https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Access-HTTP-specific-features-in-services I'm curious as to the preferred way to get to the Interface.

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside a ServiceStack [Service](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/main/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack/Service.cs) you can access the [IHttpRequest](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/main/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Web/IHttpRequest.cs) and [IHttpResponse](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/main/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Web/IHttpResponse.cs) objects with:

```
public class ContactService : Service 
{
    public object Get(Contact request)
    {
        var headerValue = base.Request.Headers[headerKey];

        //or the same thing via a more abstract (and easier to Mock):
        var headerValue = base.Request.GetHeader(headerKey);
    }
}
```

The `IHttpRequest` is a wrapper over the underlying ASP.NET HttpRequest or HttpListenerRequest (depending if you're hosting on ASP.NET or self-hosted HttpListener). So if you're running in ASP.NET you can get the underlying ASP.NET HttpRequest with:

```
var aspnetRequest = (HttpRequest)base.Request.OriginalRequest;
var headerValue = aspnetRequest.Headers[headerKey];
```

Comment: I just went back and re-read the wiki page, and found the answer in the 1st NOTE. Sorry for being brain-dead.