# How to get the Request in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, servicestack

I am posting some data to a Restful Webservice. The webservice is created using Service Stack. I want to look at the entire request that came in (write it to file), but I am unable to figure out how to access it. I want to see all the headers and the body and anything else associated with the POST request.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can access this?

Comment: You'd like to do this from the program handling the request? If it was on the client, I'd suggest Fiddler or something ;)

Comment: @JeffBridgman Exactly, Id like to do this on the server. I could do Fiddler, but Id like to have it automated

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15776876/945456

Comment: @JeffBridgman Thanks for that, I did see that post. Yes and No it helps. I was able to succesfully look at the headers but was unable to find a way to see the whole request. I tried calling `Request.GetRawBody` but this came up empty.

Comment: Fiddler have [FiddlerCore](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore) for automation...

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a built in solution, consider using [Request Logger](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-logger). It provides an in-memory logger by default, but you can subclass `IRequestLogger` and provide your own. You can also see how the in-memory logger accesses the requests by looking at its [code](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Host/InMemoryRollingRequestLogger.cs). Even if you roll your own solution, you should still be able to re-use the code from `InMemoryRollingRequestLogger`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem. What you need to do is use something like this for your DTO:

```
public class RestServiceRequest : IRequiresRequestStream
{


    public Stream stream;
    Stream IRequiresRequestStream.RequestStream
    {
        get
        {
            return stream;
        }
        set
        {
            stream = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can access the raw body in your service like so:

```
Request.GetRawBody();
```

Comment: Also consider [adding a PreRequestFilter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17514953/85785) instead.